# OneDrive folder on computer hard drive for linux

Tags: 22.04, microsoft

My colleague who uses Windows has a folder on his computer that is connected to the university's OneDrive. And this folder is created thanks to the OneDrive application on windows.

How can I, an Ubuntu 22.04.4 user, create such a folder for myself? As far as I can know, there is no OneDrive application for Linux.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/onedrive ? https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

Answer (score 1):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

There are 5 reliable ways to access OneDrive on Linux/Unix platforms:

- Via the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive - this 'syncs' your data, bi-directional operation, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business & SharePoint account types and Shared Folders. A Docker container is also available for all major architectures (i686, x86_64, ARMHF, AARCH64). If you need a GUI for onedrive client management use: https://github.com/bpozdena/OneDriveGUI
- Via the 'onedriver' client - https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver - Native file system that only provides the OneDrive 'on-demand' functionality, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business account types. Currently does not support Shared Folders or SharePoint.
- Via 'rclone' - https://rclone.org/ - one way sync client, open source and free. Has limitations with SharePoint.
- Via non-free clients such as 'insync', 'ExpanDrive'
- Via the web browser of your choice